# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC - Google Auth not working - nothing happened after execute login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, google-authentication

Right after I sign in - nothing happened
I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I read something about token.. but I don't have any access to it nor it doesn't display on the screen or something.
I thought maybe there's an option to do a if() statement inside my .cshtml so I will be able to check if the user is logged in into his google account or not.

For sure, this code doesn't work for Google authentication:

```
@if ((User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) || (Context.User != null && Context.User.Claims != null && Context.User.Claims.Count() > 0))
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Index">Categories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Restaurants" asp-action="Index">Restaurants</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Dishes" asp-action="Index">Dishes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="Index">Users</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Cities" asp-action="Index">Cities</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal">Categories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal">Restaurants</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal">Dishes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal">Users</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal">Cities</a>
                        </li>
                    }


@if ((User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) || (Context.User != null && Context.User.Claims != null && Context.User.Claims.Count() > 0))
                    {
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <li class="text-dark dropdown-toggle" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                                Hello, @User.Identity.Name!
                            </li>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                                <li><span class="dropdown-item-text">User Status: @Context.User.Claims.ToList()[1].Value</span></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Cart</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item nav-link text-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#LoginModal">
                            Hello, Guest!
                        </li>
                    }
```

Startup.cs code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FeedMe.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace FeedMe
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<FeedMeContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FeedMeContext")));

            //services.AddSession(options =>
            //{
            //    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            //});

            services.AddDbContext<FeedMeContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("FeedMeContext")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<FeedMeContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Users/Login";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Users/AccessDenied";
                })

                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Users/AccessDenied";
                })
                ;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "FeedMeContext": "XXXXXX"
  },

  "Authentication": {
    "Google": {
      "ClientId": "XXXX",
      "ClientSecret": "YYYY"
    }
  }
}
```

But it does work for the regular cookie login&register I built before

Comment: add your startup file snippet to this question as well as appsettings.config (provide enough information that we can reproduce this issue); I am specifically interested in your `IServiceConfiguration` scope, and app config scope may be relevant as well.

Comment: nevermind my last, deleted comment that was inquiry about packages and target versions.. that information is related to the tutorial that you indicated you are following (although that tutorial is not mvc - it's console).  Do include the startup and appsettings snippets though.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Added all you mentioned Brett :)
Is there any other updated and official guide that is supporting MVC? I didn't notice it was for the console.
or maybe you can help me with fixing the problem I'm having

Comment: @BrettCaswell Also, I just searched all over my project(CTRL+SHIFT+F) for "IServiceConfiguration" and I couldn't find any mention for it.

Comment: ah.. sorry, I meant `IServiceCollection `. re: `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`.. you've provided it now

Comment: @BrettCaswell Can you help me?